# JavaScript: Remove last child with class

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to remove the last element in my DOM with a specific class but I'm not having much luck.  I can remove the class entirely, but not last one by itself.  Any help would be great

```
<div class="banner banner-1"></div>
<div class="banner banner-2"></div>
<div class="banner banner-3"></div>
<div class="banner banner-4"></div>
<div class="banner banner-3"></div>
<div class="banner banner-5"></div>
```

Sorry, forgot to paste my other code in:

```
var classToRemove = 'banner-3';

document.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove))
```

For example, I have 6 banners, but banner 3 is repeated.  How do I get the last `banner-3` and remove it without affecting the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not averse to using jQuery check this PLUNKER https://plnkr.co/edit/FzPJxGjY5XZE1bH9tnuL?p=preview

Comment: This question is about javascript not jquery so closing as dupe is not accurate @ZakariAcharki

Comment: This isn't a duplicate as I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfxnxf4v/

Answer (score 3):

```
// access all elements by class
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('banner');
// find last element
var lastEle = ele[ ele.length-1 ];
//--- do what you need to do with the element
```

or

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".banner .banner_3");
var lastEle = ele[ ele.length-1 ];
lastEle.parentNode.removeChild(lastEle);
```

Comment: That will only get you the last element of all children, but not specifically the last element of a certain class like `banner-3`

Comment: @Antonvb - noticed that is the OP. Have extended the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get list by getElementsByClassName then in iteration remove them but not first

```js
for(var i=1;i<document.getElementsByClassName('banner-3').length;i++)
  document.getElementsByClassName('banner-3')[i].remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner banner-1">1</div>
<div class="banner banner-2">2</div>
<div class="banner banner-3">3</div>
<div class="banner banner-4">4</div>
<div class="banner banner-3">3</div>
<div class="banner banner-5">5</div>
```